# Add info to Crashlytics crash reports before submission

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crashlytics

Crashlytics 3.0 came with a bunch of new features. I'm mostly interested in the one that reads:

> "Runtime control over submission behavior as well as the ability to
>   add info to crashes before submission."

How can I use this feature? What info can I add to crashes?